# Numpy indexing to get values of 2nd dim depending on 1st dim

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array like

```
a = np.array([ [1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [4,5,6] ])

[[1 2 3]
 [2 3 4]
 [3 4 5]
 [4 5 6]]
```

With `a[:,-1]` I get a list with the last value of the 2nd dim: `[3 4 5 6]`.

But now, how can I be more flexible and get the values of the 2nd dim depending on the 1st dim. For example, I want the last value of the first row, the middle value of the second row and the first value of the third and forth row, so that the result is `[3 3 3 4]`.

Can I manage this directly using the numpy indexing? so far, all my efforts failed, but I don't claim that I could completely wrap my head around all the indexing mechanisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lists and pass them to the slicing operator, like so:

```
a[[0,1,2,3],[2,1,0,0]]
> array([3, 3, 3, 4])
```

The only thing you have to keep in mind is that both lists have to have the same length. What happens then is that the interpreter pairs the elements of both lists and extracts the respective elements.

Comment: Cool, that works perfectly fine. I tried something like `a[:,[2,1,0,0]]` which failed due to my misunderstanding of the indexing/slicing.

Answer (score 0):

First I "mirrored" the array then I took the diagonal and concatenated with what remains under the last element of the diagonal. Is this what you need?

If you want to customize even further check out the documentation on the diagonal you can start the diagonal at any element on the first axis.

```
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [5, 6, 7]])
>>> b = np.fliplr(a)
>>> np.concatenate((b.diagonal(), b[b.shape[1]:][:, -1]))
array([3, 3, 3, 4, 5])
>>>
```